# Set Netbeans Platform Application language

Tags: java, netbeans, bundle, netbeans-platform

When I add

```
default_options="--branding ersyp -J-Xms24m -J-Xmx64m  J-Duser.language=tr-J-Duser.region=TR"
```

code to my `appName.conf` file the NetBeans platform application language should be Turkish but when I run my application from NetBeans this file gets overwritten.
How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Is that a copy & paste error in your question, or do you really not have a space before `-J-Duser.region=..` You are also missing a `-` before the `J-Duser.language=...`

Comment: Actually the code I wrote don't have any meaning cause when I run my app this file overwritten And I don't know how I can avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
run.args.extra=--locale tr
```

in the `project.properties` file of your Netbeans application (this file is in the `Important Files` folder of your project's module suite).